# Compare binary files, ignore size mismatch

Tags: windows, unix, file-comparison

How can I compare two files and print the differences like Windows' `fc` does even if the files' sizes are different?

I need a program for windows, cygwin programs are accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Cygwin cmp command with --verbose switch.

You will get position in file and difference between bytes in decimal format.

Also you may wish to use WinMerge app. [Link](http://winmerge.org/)

Comment: Already found that out. Is there a way to make the output more like `fc`'s?

Comment: Rather not. The same but in hexadecimal format you will get using `fc /b` switch.

Comment: Well, `fc` exit if files have different sizes, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: But it can give you all the differences first. Try some switches for fc, you'll get a list by `fc /?`.

Comment: "But it can give you all the differences first." - no, it exits immediately. I've tried it before asking. Can you tell me which switch disables this behavior?

Comment: I've used `/b`, it gives me differences before quitting. I get at least one. Other switch is used to limit the number of differences printed.

Comment: You may also want to use WinMerge app.

Comment: Which windows version do you use? Can `winmerge` compare large files?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 Pro x64. WinMerge can compare any files.

Comment: Well, windows xp do it as in the question :(